# Order of execution and Thread.sleep

Tags: java, multithreading

Recently I've seen some code which depends on order of execution in different threads which was achieved by calling `Thread.sleep` with some values. It worked without any problems but I'm sure that in some rare cases it would not. I wrote some code where order of output depends on how precisely `Thread.sleep` works.

```
public class Test {
    public static Thread createDelayedPrintThread(final String text,
            final long delay) {
        return new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(delay);
                    System.out.print(text);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t1 = createDelayedPrintThread("t1", 10);
        Thread t2 = createDelayedPrintThread("t2", 10);
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

This code obliviously can output booth `t1t2` and `t2t1` so I made delays different:

```
Thread t1 = createDelayedPrintThread("t1", 10);
Thread t2 = createDelayedPrintThread("t2", 20);
```

Now it outputs `t1t2` but I still sometimes get `t2t1`. It usually happens when I do some CPU/IO intensive operations.
If I change delays to extremely big values

```
Thread t1 = createDelayedPrintThread("t1", 1_000); // one second
Thread t2 = createDelayedPrintThread("t2", 60_000); // one minute
```

would be there any guarantees that the application will output `t1t2`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your understanding is correct; no amount of `Thread.sleep()` (and by the way, since Java 5 you should really be using [`TimeUnit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html) instead, as in `TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2L)`) will guarantee in-order execution; you cannot guarantee when the OS will schedule this or that thread.

> would be there any guarantees that the application will output t1t2?

Yes.

For instance, a volatile boolean variable shared by those two threads will do (although you'll need to busy wait so this is not ideal). Another example is a [`Semaphore`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html).

Solutions are many, and what you will end up with depends entirely upon your requirements.

Comment: Don't forget that thread starting is not a sequential procedure because of setup overhead.

Comment: @xTrollxDudex sure, but then it is nevertheless ultra fast on a modern OS/hardware combination

Answer (score 3):

Thread.sleep is not guarantees.
Java tutorial, about Thread.sleep():

"However, these sleep times are not guaranteed to be precise, because they are limited by the facilities provided by the underlying OS. Also, the sleep period can be terminated by interrupts, as we'll see in a later section. In any case, you cannot assume that invoking sleep will suspend the thread for precisely the time period specified."

So, you need add other multithreading logic for guarantees execution order.